# Why won't my function call after including the file where located in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function from another file that takes 2 parameters. However, no matter what i try it won't seem to work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

```
 include '/php/withdrawlCalls/libs/paypal.php';
    $newbal=$row['balance'] - $amnt;
    $response = 0;
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $response = sendPayment($amnt,$email);
    echo $response;
```

I am positive the location of the file is correct, because I have gotten responses through ajax calls, and there is no error when i run the php file above. when trying to echo response, it just is blank

Comment: Are you sure the function `sendPayment` returns anything? Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: yes, when i run it from ajax it runs fine, and prints results out, i am trying to do this through php though, and avoid ajax for this one

Comment: The ajax call don't call `sendPayment` function... it sends a request to the server and the code in your server calls that function.

Comment: when i did it through ajax i just sent a post variable that if was set called that function, thats why it ran through ajax

Comment: and what is the data that you used there? what did you pass to that function?

Comment: for the ajax call or the php function? because the ajax call is irrelevant, i just put callfunc:'yes' in data when sent and just said if(isset$_POST['callfunc']) run function

Comment: for the php that the ajax call caused

Comment: I'm confused now lol, the way I'm doing this is calling an ajax function that runs the php code i posted above in part of it just disregard what i said prior about ajax that was just testing to make sure everything in the function works before trying to run it from an include

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a relative path in your `include` directive to ensure you are getting it correct. In most cases starting with a `/` makes it relative to your drive root unless your web root is sandboxed.  It also makes your code more portable not expecting files to be in a specific full path.

Something more like:

```
<?php
    include dirname(__DIR__) . 'libs/paypal.php';
?>
```

Just so you know `include` is a soft include request and doesn't care if it fails, `require` would fail if it can't be found.